# Why does my Axios interceptor make three more requests when the request fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, next.js, axios

[image: my current behavior]

As you can see in the GIF above, when my request fails, it retries three more times and it repeats four times in total.
I want to stop this behavior. Also, when I get 200, this does not happen and the request is made only once, I meant this only Happens when the request fails.

Also, this is my piece of code to handle the interceptor:

```
const http = axios.create({
    headers: HeadersObject,
    baseURL,
})

http.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = getTokenInformationFromLocalStorage();
        if (token) {
            config.headers["Authorization"] = `bearer ${token}`;
        } else {
            delete config.headers["Authorization"];
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

http.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        if (response.data.errors?.length) {
            response.data.errors.map((error: ErrorType) => {
                const id = uuidv4();
                store.dispatch(addToast({id, message: error.message, type: "error"}));
            });
        }
        return response
    },
    async (err) => {
        const originalConfig = err.config;
        if (err.response) {
            if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
                originalConfig._retry = true;
                try {
                    const rs = await refreshToken();
                    const {result} = rs.data;
                    if (result) {
                        setTokenInformationToLocalStorage(result);
                        http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = result.token;
                        return http(originalConfig);
                    } else {
                        store.dispatch(logout())
                        return Promise.reject("refresh token is expire!");
                    }
                } catch (_error: any) {
                    if (_error.response && _error.response.data) {
                        return Promise.reject(_error.response.data);
                    }
                    return Promise.reject(_error);
                }
            }
            if (err.response.status === 403 && err.response.data) {
                return Promise.reject(err.response.data);
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
)
```

Comment: @mandy8055 - that code wouldn't run in the case of a 400 response

Comment: that whole code that you changed should be irrelevant for http status 400 - so, not sure changing irrelevant code could hope to fix the issue described. But ... axios is weird

Comment: I believe then OP needs to handle 400 status separately.

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah my bro, This is true, I get the status code 400 and the ```originalConfig._retry``` line is not execute at all

Comment: @mandy8055 i also tried to assign false to ```originalConfig._retry```, But it still had its old behavior

Comment: @alirezatafreshi I overlooked the error status in the gif which you attached. You will need to handle 400 status separately

Comment: but why would axios repeat the request? it's supposed to only do that for 500-599 http statuses as far as I recall